# Hiding third party applications from recent apps list

Tags: android, android-recents

I have an Android 7.0 phone. It is rooted. I have written an application which always runs in the background (background service).

I was able to hide the app I have written from the recent apps list by adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the manifest.

How can I hide other third party applications (like Facebook Messenger) from the recent apps list? I thought about either changing something in the phone OS (because I have root) or by using my application (because it is always running in the background).